# Scale the nib file to fullscreen on any device respecting constrains

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, nib

I have a .xib file called "Menu" file where I design my view, then I init a class by doing the following:

```
self.menuViewController = [[TWTMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu" bundle:nil];
```

Everything is great as the the design is visualized, but the size is always 600x600. How can I do so it's full screen and adapts to the device screen size?

The nib uses autoLayout and it have constraints. I want it to go full size and respect the constrains.

Comment: self.menuViewController.frame =[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.frame

Comment: add this line after above line

Comment: Property 'frame' not found on object type TWTMenuViewController

Comment: What do the constraints look like?

Answer (score 0):

Set some constraints to the superview or change the Frame (old way)

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.superview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.superview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.superview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.superview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
}
```

Old way:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect fr = self.frame;
    fr.size = self.superview.frame.size;
    self.frame = fr;

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Now all autolayout constrains on the view will work.